# Get Count or Value via Case-When statement in oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

Can I replace the subquery in this oracle query to increase performance?

I need to differentiate between 1 or multiple counts based on a query. So if the count is 1 then display the value, otherwise display the count (or in this case, a 2 to indicate it's more than 1 as the exact number is irrelevant).

```
select t.refnum,
case count(t.acctnum) 
  when 1 then 
    ( select to_number(a.acctnum) 
      from transactions a 
      where a.refnum = t.refnum)
  else 2 
end as num_accts
from transactions t
group by t.refnum;

REFNUM        NUM_ACCTS
FF000001235   2
FF000001234   123400
FF000001236   456789
```

The output is correct, I just need to improve performance if possible. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47dd9/3)

EDIT: for the input

```
REFNUM        ACCTNUM
FF000001234   123400
FF000001234   123400
```

I need it to treat this as 1 record, as if `group by refnum, acctnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic count in a subquery so you only have to hit the table once:

```
select refnum,
  case when num_accts = 1 then to_number(acctnum) else 2 end as num_accts
from (
  select refnum,
    acctnum,
    count(acctnum) over (partition by refnum) as num_accts,
    row_number() over (partition by refnum order by null) as refnum_row
  from transactions
)
where refnum_row = 1
order by refnum, refnum_row;

REFNUM       NUM_ACCTS
----------- ----------
FF000001234     123400
FF000001235          2
FF000001236     456789
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47dd9/8) showing the result set from the subquery too. Each row form your base table is returned by that with an additional `num_accts` columns which has the same value for each row with the same `refnum`. Since you only want to see one result per `refnum` there's also another extra column that assigns a row number to each row with in each `refnum`, and the outer query only looks at the first row. This is equivalent to just having `distinct` in the outer query.

In this case the order of the accounts within a `refnum` doesn't matter as you only use the actual value if there is only one anyway; normally the `order by` in the `over` clause would be more meaningful...

---

If you can have multiple rows for a single `acctnum` within a `refnum` and you want to treat those as one, you can just add `distinct` in the `count()` clause:

```
    count(distinct acctnum) over (partition by refnum) as num_accts,
```

... i.e.:

```
select refnum,
  case when num_accts = 1 then to_number(acctnum) else 2 end as num_accts
from (
  select refnum,
    acctnum,
    count(distinct acctnum) over (partition by refnum) as num_accts,
    row_number() over (partition by refnum order by null) as refnum_row
  from transactions
)
where refnum_row = 1
order by refnum, refnum_row;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/774bd4/1) with your duplicated `FF000001234` and `123400` example.

Comment: @agrothe - the question didn't specify what to do with duplicates, and I copied the behaviour of your original version, which gives the wrong answer too based on your edit *8-) Updated the answer with `distinct` to fix that.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after the fact. Thanks